# Not able to view switches and host in Opendaylight Web Interface

Tags: opendaylight, mininet

I am using Oxygen for the Opendaylight and after installing the required features I am not able to view switches and host in Web Interface. I have created my topology in mininet.

I have followed the below link

https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-oxygen/user-guide/using-the-opendaylight-user-interface-(dlux).html

Answer (score 0):

That's not really enough info to help. have you checked that mininet switches are 
connected to opendaylight from that persepective? I think you can use ovs commands
to see if it shows as is_connected:true (e.g. ovs-vsctl show)

also try doing a GET on the ODL NB REST API, like:

```
http://$ODL_IP:8181/restconf/operational/opendaylight-inventory:nodes
```

you can double check that dlux features are installed on the karaf console with
a command like "features:list -i | grep dlux"

btw, please note that because dlux no longer had any contributions to support it,
the project has been archived and it will no longer be a part of releases
after oxygen.